# Adding a node into Jackrabbit Repository which has a HashMap Object as a property

Tags: java, jackrabbit, jcr

I want to add a node in jackrabbit Repository which has a property holding a HashMap object. What property type should be used and how It should be done?

Comment: at least add some sample code dude!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A JCR node is a hash map itself (with its properties as the keys). So, could you just add a child node?

Comment: We can add any java object as a property (of Binary type) to a node after serializing the object. I tried it with HashMap. It's working fine.